# Meaning of TensorFlow operation ` IsExpensive()`?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

There is a [method in `OpKernel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L103-L106)

```
 // Returns true iff this op kernel is considered "expensive". The
 // runtime may use this flag to optimize graph execution for example
 // to "inline" inexpensive kernels.
 virtual bool IsExpensive() { return expensive_; }
```

It seems that by default all operations on the [GPU are considered as inexpensive](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc#L99) whilst CPU, SYSL are flagged as expensive.

It is a bit hard to figure out the definition and effect of `expensive`. The is no [information in the guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op).

1. Is there any specific guideline when `IsExpensive` should be `false, true`?
2. What's the effect if an operation is flagged as expensive? So far I can only tell, that active profiling uses this [just as a hint](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/575db18083d5437fd7a87ccf3414303498911bb1/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L557-L560) 
   ? The only place querying this property is [in the scheduler](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/98b9a4e45a559217bc89960b889c130af95c1d1a/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc#L2216-L2218) but without explaining what being *inline* means.
3. In conjunction with "1." should I care about it in my custom Ops?
4. While it makes sense, that any `AsyncOp` (like [`RemoteFusedGraphExecuteOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/de0904e90669d345e0feaa89d1e99b7618fb6677/tensorflow/core/kernels/remote_fused_graph_execute_op.cc#L123)) is expensive, [`MPIAllgatherOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3e51dbba08910c14f714d2c68f4d4d2916a2b7eb/tensorflow/contrib/mpi_collectives/mpi_ops.cc#L1114-L1118) seems to be defined as not expensive. Isn't this a contradiction?

I am asking, because the [`IdentityOp`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/core/kernels/identity_op.h#L35) is explicitly marked as inexpensive. I wonder, if I should override this method in my custom ops as well, since each CPU version (even **any** custom code) is flagged as expensive.

The entire logic of XLA seems to be about wether [an instruction is expensive](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3b538660b1eb22e52ad455a17e01598508373969/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/instruction_fusion.cc#L50-L153) or not. So it might be an important part to consider. Therefore, a coin-toss about true/false might be not the best way to decide the return value in my custom op.

Comment: I have no answer to this question, but as additional info to *4)* above: the logic seems to arguably (based on the linked to comment) apply also the other way around: potentially expensive operations can be dispatched to other threads, whereas non-expensive operators are those where thread dispatching would incur a larger cost than just just dispatching on main thread ([`core/kernels/serialize_sparse_op.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5c86ae3c8487e776cc2f32c8a99410e729a3ddaf/tensorflow/core/kernels/serialize_sparse_op.cc#L89)).

Comment: [Commit related to the comment linked to above](https://git.codingcafe.org/Mirrors/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/8017c247c84c4c80fa11744b1b913aec3ee88f3e): _"Since this op only performs a constant amount of work, and typically executes in a few microseconds, it should be profitable to execute this op inline, rather than scheduling it on a remote thread."_ - from this commit message, it would seem that "inline", in this context, refers to running it on the current thread, rather than scheduling it for/dispatching it to another thread. You would probably need to ask the authors for more details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before answering your questions I think it is worth trying to understand how TensorFlow uses threads in order to get your work done. For this, I suggest you read [this related and very good SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47416445/tensorflow-execution-on-a-single-multi-core-cpu-device).

You will find that TensorFlow uses a thread-pool in order to get you work done. The expensive Ops are being scheduled for execution on the thread-pool, whereas the cheap Ops are executed "inline" meaning by the same thread which schedules the tasks (Sidenote: from the source file you have linked you find only one exception, i.e. when the `inline_ready` queue is empty the thread can execute the last expensive Op by itself.).

With this in mind, let us try to answer your questions.

> 1. Is there any specific guideline when IsExpensive should be false, true?

I could not find a specific guideline in the TensorFlow manual, however, from the internals of what we discussed above a Op should be marked to be expensive, when the offset of scheduling a task to the thread pool is neglectable in comparison to the time the task needs to be executed.

> 2. What's the effect if an operation is flagged as expensive? So far I can only tell, that active profiling uses this just as a hint ? The only place querying this property is in the scheduler but without explaining what being inline means.

The effect is the following, everytime an Ops `IsExpensive` method returns `false` it might be pushed to the `inline_ready` queue and may block the thread from performing further tasks hence stalling your programm. In contrast, if the Ops `IsExpensive` method returns true, it will be scheduled for execution on the thread pool and the scheduling thread is free to continue doing its tasks in the process loop.

> 3. In conjunction with "1." should I care about it in my custom Ops?

I think you should care and try to reason as much as possible about the execution time of you Op. After that decide how you implement the `IsExpensive` method.

> 4. While it makes sense, that any AsyncOp (like RemoteFusedGraphExecuteOp) is expensive, MPIAllgatherOp seems to be defined as not expensive. Isn't this a contradiction?

No, it is not a contradiction. If you read the comment of `MPIAllgatherOp` you will find the following:

```
// Although this op is handled asynchronously, the ComputeAsync call is
// very inexpensive. It only sets up a CollectiveOpRecord and places it
// in the table for the background thread to handle. Thus, we do not need
// a TF pool thread to perform the op.
```

Which clearly states, that scheduling this task for the thread pool would almost only be overhead. Therefore performing it inline makes a lot of sense.